# Including boolean values in Neo4j FullText Search Index

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher

I have a Full text Index on the properties of a node. The query works very well. I am using it to implement a search via an Angular UI. As an example the below returns all nodes that have a type of report and the name has the value "account:

type:report AND name:*account*

However I have some values stored against the nodes that are boolean e.g. true/false. An example is the derived property where derived is either true/false or does not exist as a property.

I want to be able to use lucene to query in this way:

type:report AND name:*account* AND derived:true

However, the query against the boolean value does not work. I expect its because teh index is only considering strings and ignores the boolean values. Is there a way I can work around this or do I need to change my model to store the boolean values as text?

I can't really create a second index (without a lot of complexity) given that the search string is coming back from a single search box in teh angular app.

Many thanks
Michael

Comment: you can filter the resultant nodes from full text search based on the 'derived' property to get the expected results

Answer (score 0):

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("indexName", "query") YIELD node, score
WHERE node.derived = $userEnteredValue
RETURN node.requiredProperty , score ORDER BY score DESC
```

i filtered the nodes based on the Boolean property after doing full text search. hope it helps .

Comment: Thanks for replying. It doesn't help. Its just putting a filter clause onto the results that come back and skipping the full text capability altogether.

Comment: and we are doing the fulltext search before applying the filter

Comment: yes. but the purpose is a search engine so the user might search for derived:true or they might also put derived:false into their search query.

Comment: ok , user is allowed to query with derived .i was of assumption that its fixed . in this case . you will have to pass it as property while querying  (updated the answer)

Comment: It still doesn't really help. What I'm trying to understand is why it doesn't work in the first place. How do people usually handle this.What are the options apart from just applying a hard coded filter against the results returned from the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207526/discussion-between-theteacher-and-n4nite).